Elementary Proof of Convolution Property
I'm giving an expository talk tomorrow about the x-ray transform, and am planning on proving its injectivity. I'm therefore looking for a simple proof of the following statement (one which certainly doesn't use the Fourier transform, for example).
Question: Let $f\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and denote by $r$ the absolute value function. Suppose $f*(1/r)=0$. Show $f=0$.
The best approach I can think of right now is to apply the Laplacian and wave my hands about integration by parts and fundamental solutions and distributions to conclude, but I'm hoping for something a bit cleaner. Also, if you can do this in $\mathbb{R}^2$, where the Laplacian approach doesn't work, that would be wonderful. Any ideas?

That seems pretty clean to me :) Is it really integration by parts? Isn't it differentiation under the integral sign that you need?

@TedShifrin well, I would need to say something about why applying the Laplacian to $1/r$ gives the delta distribution, and this uses Green's identity...
